# Scrolling fast cant set visibility hidden enough

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to remove the fixed header when leaving the table at top of scroll. But when I'm scrolling fast, my code below cant set visibility hidden fast enough and keep showing the fixed header of my table because of the loop(maybe?). How can I hide it properly? The way I fixed is not I want: Check at end of table and hide everything.

When I'm saying scrolling fast, is to holdin the bar to scroll. Or holding click to scrollbar to go down.

```
$window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var tab = $("div[name='" + tabScroll + "']")[0];
    var tableResults= tab.getElementsByClassName('results'); // get all tables(lots of tables)

    //loop all tables to check if the top scroll is inside of table specific.
    $(tableResults).each(function(index, element){
        var link = $(element);
        var offset = link.offset();
        var top = offset.top;
        var bottom = top + link.outerHeight();
        var inside = ($(document).scrollTop() >= $(element).offset().top && $(document).scrollTop() <= bottom-150)
        if(inside){
            toggleHeader(element, "visible");
        } else if($(document).scrollTop() >= $(element).offset().top && $(document).scrollTop() <= bottom){
            toggleHeader(element, "hidden");
        }
    });         
});     

function toggleHeader(x, v) {
    $(x).find('thead').css('visibility', v);
    $(x).parent().parent().find('.float-left-div').children().css('visibility', v);
}
```

Comment: How large is the array of `tableResults`? The loop iterating over that array is firing every time a scroll event is fired, most likely is causing the hangup you're noticing. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll. The example they have in that article I think is close to what you want.

Comment: 1 to 180 tables, depends the filter that user want to see

Comment: It improved a little, but still not applying the visibility as expected when scrolling very very fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each scroll, it will calls else if + else if Outside of everything. Code below inside of each loop.

```
var element = angular.element(val);

var positionOutsideOfTable = $(element).offset().top + $(element).outerHeight();
var inside = (scrollY >= $(element).offset().top && scrollY <= positionOutsideOfTable - 200);

if (inside) {
    // I'm inside of this table yay
} else if (scrollY >= $(element).offset().top && scrollY <= positionOutsideOfTable + $(document).height()) {
    // I'm below the table and at same time I'm out of everything :(
} else {
    // I'm out of everything
}
```